# Material UI: File Upload using ButtonBase

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, material-ui

In Material UI Documentation, they showed how to create an "Upload" button by hiding the input file and then adding the Button component inside the label. (see: https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/)

Now, I want a different button, so I'm working with ButtonBase but it's not working - file select pop-up doesn't show. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything, maybe I'm missing some parameter to pass it?

```
<input
    accept="image/*"
    className="d-none"
    id="image-upload"
    type="file"
  />
  <label htmlFor="image-upload"
    className="d-block" >
    <Button component="span">
      Upload
    </Button> {/* working */}
    <ButtonBase>
      test
    </ButtonBase>  {/* not working*/}
 </label>
```

ButtonBase API: https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, what version are you running? Material-UI is a *very* fast project so you need to make sure you're checking the documentation for whatever version you are at.

I favor using explicit events (`ref` in this case) and this works for me under `3.1.0`

```
<input 
  ref={'file-upload'}
  type='file'
/>
<ButtonBase
  onClick={e => {
    this.refs['file-upload'].click()
  }}
>
  <div style={{
    color: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    border: '1px solid green',
  }}
  >
    Upload!
  </div>
</ButtonBase>
<hr />
<Button
  type='file'
  onClick={e => {
    this.refs['file-upload'].click()
  }}
>
  File Upload Material
</Button>
```

I use something similar to this in one of my projects and I just hide the `<input type='file' />` element.

Comment: Thank you! Let me give it a try, but i notice that you added an onClick function? Do you know why does the Button Component works even without it?

Comment: @AbigailA. I do not as I'm not quite sure how it is rendering, but I suspect that it is directly rendering a `<button>` tag rather than rendering nothing like the `ButtonBase` component does. You can always inspect the element to see what's happening behind the scenes. I bet a `<ButtonBase><button /></ButtonBase>` would have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

the same can be implement with hooks

```
export default function myForm(props) { 
 const inputEl = React.useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("inside")
    // `current` points to the mounted file input element
    inputEl.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        Upload Photos
          <br/>
          <input
        accept="image/*"
        className={classes.input}
        id="outlined-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
        ref={inputEl}
      />
      <label htmlFor="outlined-button-file">

        <ButtonBases
        onClick={()=>onButtonClick()}
        />
      </label>
    </React.Fragment>
)}
```

Don't forget to call onClick inside ButtonBasses component.

```
export default function ButtonBases(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
       <ButtonBase
          ...
          onClick={props.onClick}
        >
          ....
        </ButtonBase>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```